# cat/sed an iOS executable file - error on macOS

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sed

When I `cat` or `sed` an iOS executable file, it always interrupts, and I get the following message:

```
$ 1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c
```

when I press Enter, I get:

```
$ 1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c1;2c
-bash: 1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c1: command not found
-bash: 2c: command not found
```

Comment: Your question's title mentions macOS, but you've tagged your question `linux`. Which is it? The answer you've accepted uses _GNU_ `sed` syntax, which points to Linux rather than macOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should work as long as you don't output any of the binary content to the terminal. make a copy and use `sed -i` to modify the copy in-place:

```
cp file file.modified
sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/' file.modified
```

then use e.g. `vimdiff` to verify the change (after using `fold` to put newlines in the files):

```
fold -w40 file > file.40
fold -w40 file.modified > file.modified.40
vimdiff file.40 file.40
```

Answer (score 1):

Terminals are not meant to handle binary file content.  They will cause all kinds of unwanted behavior, likely because of the terminal interpreting some of the content as specific character sequences with special meaning which never occur in normal content (unless specifically meant to be sent to the terminal for control purposes).

Comment: Is there some good way to handle this problem， i want to use sed to replace string

Comment: I have never needed to do that, it would not be as straightforward as for a normal text file, but here is an approach found with a quick web search for "binary file search and replace linux" : http://everydaywithlinux.blogspot.ca/2012/11/patch-strings-in-binary-files-with-sed.html.  Never tried myself, cannot vouch for it.

Comment: One thing to note is that, in a binary file, when replacing text it is important that the binary contents (typically code or data encoded in a non-readable format) does not move.  You will need to replace a string with another of the same length (padded somehow if necessary).  Offsetting or overwriting any binary data will probably cause the program to crash, and in the "best" case corrupt data.